# Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument crash

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I try to create pdf file with `NotesDocumentCollection`(a collection) or a `notesuidocument`

1. problem - When i try with a base with `NotesDocumentCollection`, it
   works to create a pdf in the document but i can't extract them... i
   can't see
2. problem - when i try with a base with `notesuidocument` : it's crash
       !!

I want to use the same code with the two type of base...

This is my code :

```vb
Public Sub sauverPdfPiecesJointes       

Dim s As NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim colldoc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument    
Dim resultat As String  
Dim monRepertoire As Repertoire 
Dim monXml As Xml
Dim fichierExiste As Integer        
Dim i As Integer
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument        
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace   
Dim flagUidoc As Integer
Dim nb As String 
Dim vue As NotesView


Set s = New NotesSession()          

'initialisation de la variable
totalResultat = ""          

Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
dbFilePath = db.FilePath
dbFileName = db.FileName        
'initialisation du compteur
i = 0
flagUidoc = 0

'creation du pdf du document    
Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument   <==== CRASH HERE
Set colldoc = db.UnprocessedDocuments    


If (uidoc Is Nothing) Then
'plusieurs documents sont sélectionnés
    If (colldoc.Count > 0) Then 
        Set doc = colldoc.GetFirstDocument
        While Not doc Is Nothing                        
            (creation du pdf....) (...)                                 
            i = i + 1
            Set  doc = colldoc.GetNextDocument(doc)             
        Wend                                    
    End  If
' l'utilisateur est dans le document    
Else                        
    flagUidoc = 1   
    'si l'utilisateur a fait une modification
    Set doc = uidoc.Document
    nb = doc.Universalid            
      Call uidoc.Close(true)
    Delete uidoc
    Set doc = db.Getdocumentbyunid(nb)

    (creation du pdf....) (...)

    Set vue = db.Getview(nomVue)
    Call vue.Refresh()

End If
```

Comment: Usually this line would not crash. There has to be something else in the code or in the application that makes it crash. And the other question is not even understandable. Please describe what EXACTLY happens...just in case: you do not use 8.5.0, do you? Because this version sometimes did crash on that command...

Comment: How is this code running? Is it in an action button? It cannot work in an agent, because the NotesUI classes only work in front-end contexts.

Comment: I wouldn't assume this poster means it crashes Notes -- they might just mean that the agent errors out.

Answer (score 1):

I will update the question if you post more details based on this answer.

1. Go to your IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder and find the latest NSD.
2. Open it and look for the word FATAL. This will give you the crash stack. Add that to your question and it will give more details.

To understand in more detail there is a [wiki article](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Mapping__agent_code_to_NSD_crash_stack_on_Windows) explains how to determine crashing code (although you are pointing to it, frontEnd classes don't aways behave how you expect them).

As for NotesUIWorkspace. There were issues in earlier versions of Notes (I think R8.0, or possibly R7). The issue was if you opened a Notes client but didn't open a database before executing the code, the NotesUIWorkspace would not initialise fully. It's a edge case, so not obvious.

You can also try using other methods on the NotesUIWorkspace object before touching the document. See if it crashes as well.

Other then this, for your code to work it also needs to have a document in context in the front end. So if you have not selected a document, or have a document open then it should fail (but not crash).

You can also use the [LND tool](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Using_the_LND_tool_to_analyze_IBM_Lotus_Notes_and_Domino_hangs_and_crashes) to get more details on the nature of the crash.

Comment: thanks i will look for this if i don't find solution !

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing your code I assume that

- it is an agent
- with target option "All selected documents" and
- shall work on current opened document or on selected documents in view

The usual pattern for this kind of jobs is to look

- *first* for selected documents in view with `database.UnprocessedDocuments` and if no documents are selected
- *second* for opened document in UI or for marked document in view with `session.DocumentContext`

This way you **don't need a NotesUIDocument** and with following code example you have to call your pdf creation code only once:

```vb
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim col As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase    
Set col  = db.UnprocessedDocuments
If col Is Nothing Then
    Set doc = session.DocumentContext
Else
    Set doc = col.GetFirstDocument
End If
While Not doc Is Nothing
    '
    ' create pdf for doc here ....
    '
    If col Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = nothing
    else
        Set doc = col.GetNextDocument(doc)      
    End If
Wend
```

Comment: i will try this and i'll come back, thanks a lot (sorry for the delay i was on holidays...)